# HttpRequestMessage configure IP in multi-IP environment

Tags: c#

I have several IPs on a host and want to choose which is used when I make a connection from a `HttpClient` with a `HttpRequestMessage`. Can this be done without me going down to sockets and writing a simple http client myself?

*I'm looking for an equivalent of `bind` before `connect` at `socket` level but for `HttpClient`... or an alternative.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if you are using the default `HttpClient` message handler on a Windows machine, `HttpClient` will be using the .Net `HttpWebRequest` to do its work. This in turn, relies on the `ServicePointManager` to provide a `ServicePoint` to manage connections to the URI. For any domain, you can hook into its `ServicePoint` to change the way it binds to an IPEndPoint.

If you take the URI that you are trying to connect to and find its `ServicePoint`:

```
var sp = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(uri);
```

then you can:

```
var sp = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
sp.BindIPEndPointDelegate = (servicePoint, remoteEndPoint, retryCount) => {
    IPAddress adapterIpAddress = //your chosen adapter's IP address
    return new IPEndPoint(adapterIpAddress, 0);
};
```

If you want to get really jazzy, you could fold this into a DelegatingHandler so that the HttpClient takes care of everything for you:

```
public class RebindingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private BindIPEndPoint bindHandler;
    public RebindingHandler(IEnumerable<IPAddress> adapterAddresses, 
                            HttpMessageHandler innerHandler = null)
        : base(innerHandler ?? new WebRequestHandler())
    {
        var addresses = adapterAddresses.ToList();
        if(!addresses.Any())
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        var idx = 0;
        bindHandler = (servicePoint, remoteEndPoint, retryCount) => {
            int i = Interlocked.Increment(ref idx);
            uint i2 = unchecked((uint)i);
            int index = (int)(((long)i2) % addresses.Count);

            IPAddress adapterIpAddress = addresses[index];
            return new IPEndPoint(adapterIpAddress, 0);
        };
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var sp = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(request.RequestUri);
        sp.BindIPEndPointDelegate = bindHandler;
        var httpResponseMessage = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        return httpResponseMessage;
    }
}
```

Then you can:

```
var addresses = new List<IPAddress>(); //this contains your adapter addresses
var client = new HttpClient(new RebindingHandler(addresses));
```

and when you use `client`, the inner handler will automatically enroll the relevant ServicePoint to use a BindIPEndPoint that rotates around a bunch of IPEndPoints.

Comment: I'll be hitting a single domain. I just need it to see different IP addresses. Is there a way to avoid mentioning a URI there?

Comment: @CodeAngry I wrote a delegating handler that should do everything you need.

Comment: @CodeAngry I made a change to the code to avoid a concurrency issue.

Comment: I got it. I'll deal with anything else from here. I know where to start now. Thanks!

Comment: @CodeAngry Good, because I tested nothing here :)

Comment: @CodeAngry working on same issue for days now and the solution provided is still getting me same servicepoint for each binding to different ip.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36217696/webrequests-with-binding-different-ips-using-bindipendpointdelegate-does-not-res

Comment: @devprashant Ended up writing a minimalist socket HTTP client that fit my needs. After some testing, none of these methods were reliable or fast enough for what I wanted to do.

Comment: @CodeAngry Implemented  socket and using socket.bind() to bind to specific NIC. Still only 2 NICs are working at a time. When data from 1 out of 2 NIC  gets completely downloaded then only data download starts from 3rd NIC.