# webrequests with Binding different IPs using BindIPEndPointDelegate does not result in multiple ServicePoints for same host in multi-thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, httpwebrequest, servicepoint

## Category:

Throughput Increment

## Scenario:

Multiple HttpWebRequests **need** to be send through different ethernet adapters to the same host.

## Keys to Remember:

- Requests are going to same host.
- There is a built in limit on per-host basis as servicepoint.
- Number of simultaneous requests to a host can be leveraged by setting 
  System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit to 100 (for example),
  or by setting webRequest.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 50 (say) for a     webrequest objects with same uri .
  *Sources:*

  - [Max number of concurrent HttpWebRequests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361771/max-number-of-concurrent-httpwebrequests) (Question)

    - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1361781/3690154 (Answer)
    - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1361932/3690154 (Answer)
  - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adarshk/2005/01/02/understanding-system-net-connection-management-and-servicepointmanager/ (Discussion)

## Sample Code:

[Complete Gist](https://gist.github.com/devprashant/4973b5a10d6b38b38c76)(Target Framework .Net 2.0)
.

```
Uri url = new Uri("https://d585tldpucybw.cloudfront.net/docs/default-source/fiddler/fiddler4setup.exe?sfvrsn=80");

        ServicePoint sp = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(url);

        sp.BindIPEndPointDelegate = delegate (
            ServicePoint servicePoint,
            IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint,
            int retryCount)
        {                
            // If IPs referenced in localpoint does not exists, this delegate retries a 7000+ times in few seconds, blocking other threads. Take care!!!
            Console.WriteLine("Retry count segment " + segmentEndPoint.segNumber + " is " + retryCount + " for eth with ip " + segmentEndPoint.ipEndPoint);
            //Console.WriteLine("ip: " + segmentEndPoint.ipEndPoint);
            if (retryCount < 200)
            {
                return segmentEndPoint.ipEndPoint;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        };

        sp.ConnectionLimit = 5;
        sp.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 0;

        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        webRequest.Proxy = null; // if not set, HttpWebRequest searches system-wide proxy settins which takers 2-8 seconds!
        webRequest.ConnectionGroupName = segmentEndPoint.segNumber + "hey";

        webRequest.KeepAlive = false;

        Console.WriteLine("ServicePoint: {0}, Thread: {1}", webRequest.ServicePoint.GetHashCode(), segmentEndPoint.segNumber);

        var response = webRequest.GetResponse();
        response.Close();
```

## want to do:

webreq1 ----- to be sent through ------- eth1
webreq2 ----- to be sent through ------- eth2
webreq3 ----- to be sent through ------- eth3

## what is happening:

- If webreq1 --- sents through connection ---- eth1

  - webreq2 -- sents through connection ---- eth1 ( which is bind to eth2 )
  - webreq3 -- sents through connection ---- eth1 ( which is bind to eth3 )
- webRequest.ServicePoint.GetHashCode() gives same hash for all webrequests.

## Problems (Not Solved):

- Each webrequest is using the same servicepoint ,although explicitly set to use different ethernet connections via BindIPdelegate on ServicePoint for each HttpWebRequest.

## Problems (Resolved):

- Multiple Request to same host from webrequests in different threads. (Resolved via setting servicepoint.ConnectionLimit)(Source mentioned above).

## Further Solution (to be implemented, if not solved):

- Using Raw Socket.
- This solution may not work if depends on same servicemanager-servicepoint scenario.

Requested Suggestions. 
Regards.
devprashant.

Comment: If you want some more info, feel free to comment here. thanks.

Comment: req1, 2 & 3 all to the same host?

Comment: @spender. Yes. Its mentioned above in " keys to remember" section.

Comment: gist for guideX and gufi from irc based on there recommendation https://gist.github.com/devprashant/10c2f380a517ec1b6b9f65b4a3559120

Comment: i have started to build something like this, but then i found that binding to certain network adapter don't work while using proxy and https :/

Comment: @devprashant Hello devprashant. I have a similar issue. Have you found a solution? See my post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52096275/binding-web-requests-to-specific-network-adapter